# Angular: translation pipe - visual helper

Tags: angular, translation, angular-pipe

So my scope is that on dev mode I show on the page the translation strings (in orange color for example)..

so, we have a translation pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslationService } from 'app/services/translation.service';
const getByKey = require('lodash.get');

    @Pipe({
      name: 'translate'
    })
    export class TranslatePipe implements PipeTransform {

      constructor(public _translation: TranslationService) {}

      transform(value: string, args?: string): any {
        console.log('KEY: ', value, 'ENGLISH', args);
        return getByKey(this._translation.store, value) || args;
      }
    }
```

and we are using it in our view like

```
{{ 'global.key' | translate 'Translated text' }}
```

works great...

now, we would like to flush those ones that are translated with the pipe.... so they are visible on the page... to give our translation page a better overview of what is going on (what has been translated and what is still missing)

now, if we were to use

that would be simple, would be something like this

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslationService } from 'app/services/translation.service';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
const getByKey = require('lodash.get');

@Pipe({
  name: 'translate'
})
export class TranslatePipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(public _translation: TranslationService, private _sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  transform(value: string, args?: string): any {
    console.log('KEY: ', value, 'ENGLISH', args);
    return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml('<span class="translated">' + (getByKey(this._translation.store, value) || args) + '</span>');
  }
}
```

but we are not... we are not using innerHTML.... and to implement it cross site it would quiet a hefty task...

so is there any other way to put a html/css wrapper to our pipe translated texts?

any idea is welcome

Answer (score 0):

I guess, there is no way to wrap it with html without using `[innerHTML]` or `[outerHTML]`. Pipes are meant to transform data, but not really to change the DOM.

I see the possibility to use a component instead of a pipe, where you easily could solve this with an `@Input`.

But I guess the easiest solution is using `[outerHTML]`, since it's automatically sanitized by Angular. As long as the translation service does not return anything unexpected, everything should work (otherwise you would get an error):

> To systematically block XSS bugs, Angular treats all values as untrusted by default. When a value is inserted into the DOM from a template, via property, attribute, style, class binding, or interpolation, Angular sanitizes and escapes untrusted values.
>   (https://angular.io/guide/security)

Change the view like that (note, after `translate` there must be a `:`

```
<div [outerHTML]="'global.key' | translate: 'Translated text'"></div>
```

Change your `transform`-function as follows:

```
transform(value: string, args?: string): any {
   console.log('KEY: ', value, 'ENGLISH', args);
   const translation = getByKey(this._translation.store, value);
   return translation ? `<span class="translated">${translation}</a>` : args;
}
```

Comment: so meaning, we would need and go and refactor all our translations like this? :/

Comment: ok, now i understand. you can't really change the existing part in the view, right?

Comment: well, I could, but its a big effort, talking about days... so we need to explore other options first

Comment: is using a regex for refactoring an option? Most IDEs and editors support regex search and replace. Search for `\{\{ ('.*') \| translate '([^']*)' \}\}` and replace it with `<div [outerHTML]="$1 | translate: '$2'"></div>` (might be editor-specific)